# Getting Synax error: SyntaxError unexpected token in json at position 2 aws-lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

Through Bitbucket, I'm passing an environmental variable object through the development tab that looks similarly to:

`{ "var1": "tets.var.com",   "port": "34",   "username": "john",   "password": "pass", "env": "dev" }`

I am also passing these variables through my Bitbucket pipeline as:

`npx cdk deploy app --require-approval never -c credentials="$BITBUCKET_CRED"`

However, when invoking my lambda with the credentials, I am getting the error:

`"SyntaxError: Unexpected token \\ in JSON at position 2"`

Answer (score -1):

My problem was that the object I passed in was too long, hence the "//" in the response. I'm assuming the "//n" was left off

Comment: I'm sure you've fixed the problem but this answer doesn't seem to clearly describe the root cause.